# How to insert Foreignkey value into a table which doesnt exist yet

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, rdbms

I have a situation, I have two tables namely ,User and Company .
Here is my User table :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User](
[UserId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[UserName] [nvarchar](500) NOT NULL,
[Password] [nvarchar](500) NOT NULL,    
[CompanyId] [int] NULL,
[LastModUserId] [int] NOT NULL,
[LastModDttm] [datetime] NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT [PK_User] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
  [UserId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[User]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_User_Company] FOREIGN KEY([CompanyId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Company] ([CompanyId])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[User] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_User_Company]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[User]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_User_User1] FOREIGN KEY([LastModUserId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[User] ([UserId])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[User] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_User_User1]
 GO
```

Here is my Company Table :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Company](
[CompanyId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[CompanyName] [nvarchar](500) NOT NULL,
[Address1] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
[Address2] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
[LastModUserId] [int] NOT NULL,
[LastModDttm] [datetime] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Company] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[CompanyId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,       ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
 ) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Company]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Company_User] FOREIGN KEY([LastModUserId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[User] ([UserId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Company] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Company_User]
GO
```

My problem :

I want to create a company record,I haven't created a user yet.When I Insert into the LastModUserId columun it will throw the error "Cannot Insert the value NULL into column 'LastModUserId' ,table MYDb.dbo.Company' , column does not allow nulls.INSERT fails.

If I try to insert a record into the User Table ,there is also the same problem ,there is CompanyId column,which doesn't allow nulls either

How do I handle this situation ?

Comment: This is a many-to-many relation and you will have to move linking fields to an intermediate table. There's plenty of resources on the internet that will teach you how to do this.

Comment: Why don't you change `LastModUserId` to `int NULL`?

Comment: @podiluska,If I do like that, its a violation of  referential integrity right ?

Comment: disable the contraint, insert the record, re-enable the constraint.

Comment: Disable FK_User_User1 constraint to create super user record. Afterwards enable this constraint.

Comment: @BhasyakaruluKottakota , how do I do this ,will u provide an example

Comment: So this is OK? To create a company, first I need a user. To create a user, first I need a company. **Obviously** you have created this dependency. The solution is to break it, because you will have to temporarily break it anyway in order to get the values into the database.

Answer (score 1):

Disable constraint to enter super record.

```
ALTER TABLE [User] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_User_User1];
     GO
     ALTER TABLE [User] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_User_Company];
     GO
     DECLARE @USERID AS INT, @COMPANYID AS INT;
     SELECT @USERID = 1, @COMPANYID = 1;
     SET IDENTITY_INSERT [User] ON;
     INSERT INTO [User](
     [UserId],
    [UserName],
    [Password],
    [CompanyId],
    [LastModUserId], 
    [LastModDttm]
    )
    select
    @USERID,
    'Super',
    'Passw0rd',
    1,
    1,
    getdate();

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [User] OFF;

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Company] ON;

    insert into [Company](
    [CompanyId],
    [CompanyName],
    [Address1],
    [Address2],
    [LastModUserId],
    [LastModDttm])
    select
    @COMPANYID,
    'cOMANY a',
    'Address 1',
    'Address 2',
    @USERID,
    getdate();

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Company] OFF;
    go
     ALTER TABLE [User] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_User_User1];
     GO
     ALTER TABLE [User] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_User_Company];
     GO
```